# Python Regex Match Leading Space, starting-text and Everything inside Curly Braces

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am new to regex and I want some suggestion for my code please.
I have the following code in python:

```
import re

textToSearch = """ 
hello{
    @hi {
        I want this text
    }

    @hola {
        I don't want this text
    }
} 
"""

regex= r'(?<=@hi {)[^}]*'
result = re.findall(regex,textToSearch)

print(result)
```

> #Output =  ['\n        I want this text\n    ']

What I want as a output is:

> @hi {
> #everything in here
> }
>
> including *leading space* and *curly braces* of **@hi**

I would appreciate any suggestion to solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include `hi` in the match instead of asserting it to the left, and match spaces without newlines using `[^\S\r\n]*`.

If you also want to match the leading newlines, you can use `\s*`

```
[^\S\r\n]*@hi\b[^\S\r\n]*{[^{}]*}
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PafKi8/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jD1jE1)

The pattern matches:

- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ whitespace chars without a newline
- `@hi\b` Match `@hi`
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ whitespace chars without a newline
- `{[^{}]*}` Match from `{` till `}` using a negated character class matching any char (include matching newlines) except the curly's

For example

```
import re

textToSearch = """ 
hello{
    @hi {
        I want this text
    }

    @hola {
        I don't want this text
    }
} 
"""

regex= r'[^\S\r\n]*@hi\b[^\S\r\n]*{[^{}]*}'
result = re.findall(regex,textToSearch)

print(result)
```

Output

```
['    @hi {\n        I want this text\n    }']
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. Sorry, I made a typo in my code. Just corrected. How can I also grab '@' ?

Comment: @vuspomagnu Like this? `[^\S\r\n]*@hi\b[^\S\r\n]*{[^{}]*}` https://regex101.com/r/PafKi8/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex pattern to match your text :

```py
pattern = r'@hi \{\n\s+(?P<text>[\w ]+)\n\s+\}'
match_result = re.search(pattern, textToSearch)

# To get all the found value
match_found = match_result.group(0)

# To get the text only
needed_text = match_result['text']

print(match_found)
print(needed_text)
```

Here is the explanation of the pattern :

- `\n` for newline
- `\s` for space
- `\w` for alpanumeric
- `(?P<group_name>[pattern_value])` for a group seach
- `+` for one or more value

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. Sorry, I made a typo in my code. Just corrected. How can I also grab '@' ?

Comment: Just add the at symbol where the *hi* is in the pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do not have enough reputation to upvote you. But I really appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem with that, don't forget this when you can upvote one day. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using regex flags to expand meaning of `^` and `.` you can use this pattern:

```py
import re

textToSearch = """ 
hello{
    @hi {
        I want this text
    }

    @hola {
        I don't want this text
    }
} 
"""

# regex = '(?sm)^\s*@hi\s*{.*?}'  # non-verbose version

regex= r'''(?smx)  # DOTALL|MULTILINE|VERBOSE flags
           ^       # start of line (due to MULTILINE)
           \s*     # any amount of whitespace
           @hi     # match exactly these characters
           \s*     # any amount of whitespace
           {.*?}   # capture everything up between braces (due to DOTALL)
        ''' 

result = re.findall(regex,textToSearch)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['    @hi {\n        I want this text\n    }']
```